# Map param to function - fmap ($ 3) (4+)

Tags: haskell

Reading [Function application with $](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions#function-application) in Learn You Haskell book I found example of applying $ to list of functions.

```
map ($ 3) [(4+), (10*), (^2), sqrt]
```

I wanted try similar thing and reduce example to applying to one function

```
fmap ($ 3) (4+)
```

But I am getting errors which I don't understand

```
• Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num (a -> b)
  (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
• When checking the inferred type
    it :: forall a b. (Num (a -> b), Num a) => (a -> b) -> b
```

Could you help me understand why it works in the first case but it doesn't in the second? How can I achieve desired effect?

Thank you

Comment: Minor clarification: I get a different error when I try `fmap ($ 3) (4+)` in GHCi ("Non type-variable argument in the constraint [...]"). Are you using GHC 7.10 or later (cf. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31503707/2751851) and the P.S. to the accepted answer)? If so, could you please double-check what the error message is?

Comment: Thank you @duplode for clarification question. I am using ghc 8.0.2. I am getting now same error as you wrote. I will update description. Maybe I copied wrong error from previous experiments with getting this right.

Comment: Both work as you want in my GHCi. The only difference is the second argument which must be a list, not a tuple. `map ($ 3) [(4 + )]` and `fmap ($ 3) [(4 + )]`  You can have a wrapper function to make a tuple into a partial function in a list if desired.

Answer (score 6):

You need `map` in the first example because you have a whole *container* full of functions, and *each* of them you want to apply to the number. In that example, you could indeed also replace `map` with `fmap`, which does work on any container (on any *functor*).

```
Prelude> fmap ($ 3) [(4+), (10*), (^2), sqrt]    -- list functor
[7.0,30.0,9.0,1.7320508075688772]
Prelude> fmap ($ 3) (Just (4+))                  -- `Maybe` functor
Just 7
Prelude> fmap ($ 3) (do y<-readLn; return (y+))  -- `IO` functor
> 100
103
```

However, `(4+)` by itself is not a function wrapped in any functor, it's just a function by itself. So, you don't really need any `fmap`:

```
Prelude> ($ 3) (4+)
7
```

Of course you could simplify that even further to `4+3`...

If for some reason you do need to use `fmap` regardless<sup>†</sup>, you'd need it to operate in the *identity functor*:

```
Prelude> :m +Data.Functor.Identity
Prelude Data.Functor.Identity> fmap ($ 3) (Identity (4+))
Identity 7
```

The identity functor is a very boring container that just *always contains exactly one element*.

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>That's not unrealistic BTW: in Haskell we like to keep code as generic as possible. You may have a function that is able to work with arbitrary functors (more typically, arbitrary *monads*, which are special functors) but may want to use it in the trivial context of *just one element contained*. Or, you may want to stack different monad functionalities as *monad transformers*; then you'll generally start with `Identity` as the “vanilla monad”.</sub>

Comment: My initial reaction to the question was "You can't do that!  Wait... you *should* be able to do that, because the identity functor is still a functor... Hmm..."  Do you know if there's a reason Haskell can't automatically interpolate identity functors where they're semantically required?

Comment: @DanielMcLaury how would you know when they are semantically required? You'd need a classification between “functor-y values” and “plain-ish values”. But in Haskell, types are ab initio black boxes – a polymorphic function has no way to investigate whether the type it works with has any extra structure. What you can do is require that a type must be functor-wrapped, but to typecheck that the compiler must be able to clearly separate it to something of the form `f a`. For instance `Int` is not of this form, but there's actually no way to prove that from within the language.

Comment: ...mind though: you _can_ write, for example, `7 :: Identity Int`, because `Identity Int` has a `Num` instance and can thus be instantiated directly with number literals.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury Also, on a slightly pedantic note, `Identity` isn't the only way to trivially make a functorial value out of anything. There is also, at least, `Const`.

Comment: Thank you @leftaroundabout, I didn't know `($3)  (4+)` works :)  Could you please elaborate how (4+) is not a functor ? Aren't functions functors ?

Comment: @ŠefčíkováJana yes, functions _are_ functors, in the sense that there is `instance Functor ((->) a)`. But this instance unfortunately makes it hard to see which mapping is a functor-map and which is just a plain function; IMO it would be better if that instance didn't exist. (There's a more explicit name for the function functor which avoids the confusion: [Reader](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.5.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Reader.html).)

Comment: Also, technical nitpicking: `(4+)` is not a functor and neither is `[1,2,3]`, those are just _container values_. The actual functor is the _function type constructor_, or the _list type constructor_.

Comment: Thank you for note, I didn't met so far 'container' values term, is this name for instances such as (4+), [1,2,3] ?I am also not sure what is 'plain' function. With my limited knowledge, I don't see any difference between functions (4+) and ($3). Why we suddenly use Identity ?

Comment: The main difference between the functions `(4+)` and `($3)` is in the type: the former is just a simple `Int -> Int` endofunction, whereas `($3)` is a _higher-order function_ of type `(Int -> Int) -> Int`. — “Why we suddenly use Identity” – well, we _don't_, normally; as I explained, you would usually just _apply_ the function without ever considering any functors. Function application is just juxtaposition in Haskell, thus `($3) (4+)`.

Answer (score 2):

I would say the main issue is that your `(4 +)` is not wrapped correctly inside a functor. If you inspect the type of `fmap` you'll get:

```
Prelude> :t fmap
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

In your first example, all the functions were wrapped in a list. Here if you change your `(4 +)` into `[ (4 +) ]`, it will work.

As for the explanation about functor, you'll probably find more documentation online (or in the comment section :D Thanks for the feedback)

Comment: This has nothing to do with `Monad`s, but with `Functor`s.

Comment: Does it makes sense to replace 'monad' with 'functor' in my answer or would it be nonsense ?

Comment: well you write "wrapped [correctly] inside a monad", but a monad is not a constructor, you can not really *wrap* something in a Monad I think. Here the idea is that `(4 +)` is a functor (since `(->) a` is a functor), but that does not work nicely with `$ 3`.

Comment: To be fair a monad is just a monoid in the category of endofunctors, meaning it's an endofunctor together with some extra structure. So if it makes sense to talk about"wrapping something in a functor," it makes an equal amount of sense to talk about "wrapping something in a monad," although I don't love either piece of terminology. That said `fmap` is for arbitrary endofunctors, not just monads, so it's a better thing to use here.

Answer (score 2):

`fmap` applies a function to values found in some functorial value. In `fmap ($ 3) [(4+), (10*), (^2), sqrt]`, the list is the functorial value, and the function `($ 3)` is applied to its elements. As for `fmap ($ 3) (4+)`, [leftaroundabout correctly points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49651416/2751851) that:

> However, `(4+)` by itself is not a function wrapped in any functor, it's just a function by itself.

In this case, there is a complementary way to look at it. `(4+)` is a functorial value; however, the functor isn't the one you need. Functions are functors, and, for the purposes of `fmap`, the values "found in them" are the results of the function:

```
GHCi> :set -XTypeApplications
GHCi> :t fmap @((->) _)
fmap @((->) _) :: (a -> b) -> (w -> a) -> w -> b
```

`fmap` for functions applies a function to the results of another function, which amounts to function composition. So this...

```
GHCi> fmap (4*) (2+) 1
12
```

... is the same as:

```
GHCi> ((4*) . (2+)) 1
12
```

In your case, we have:

```
GHCi> :t (4+)
(4+) :: Num a => a -> a
```

So `fmap f (4+)` will apply `f` to the `Num a => a` result of `(4+)`. The type of `($ 3)`, though, is:

```
GHCi> :t ($ 3)
($ 3) :: Num a => (a -> b) -> b
```

And so `fmap ($ 3)` will expect a functorial value with functions to be possibly found in it:

```
GHCi> :t fmap ($ 3)
fmap ($ 3) :: (Num a, Functor f) => f (a -> b) -> f b
```

Putting it all together, we get:

```
GHCi> :t fmap ($ 3) (4+)
fmap ($ 3) (4+) :: (Num (a -> b), Num a) => (a -> b) -> b
```

The type error this will lead to has to do with the `Num (a -> b)` constraint. If there are functions to be found in `(4+)`, then `4` itself must be a function. As `4` is a numeric literal, its type must be also an instance of `Num`. However, there is no `Num` instance for functions. Trying `fmap ($ 3) (4+)` leads to an error which mentions `Num (a -> b)`. That should suggest something is off:

```
GHCi> fmap ($ 3) (4+)

<interactive>:33:1: error:
    * Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num (a -> b)
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    * When checking the inferred type
        it :: forall a b. (Num (a -> b), Num a) => (a -> b) -> b
```

The "Non-type variable argument" complaint, though, is a bit of a distraction, induced by numeric literals being polymorphic. We can get a more straightforward error either by enabling `FlexibleContexts` and then trying to use `fmap ($ 3) (4+)` (which will lead to `Num a => a` being specialised to `Integer` thanks to the defaulting rules)...

```
GHCi> :set -XFlexibleContexts
GHCi> fmap ($ 3) (4+) (2*)

<interactive>:39:1: error:
    * No instance for (Num (Integer -> Integer))
        arising from a use of `it'
        (maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?)
    * In the first argument of `print', namely `it'
      In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

... or by specialising the numeric type through a type annotation:

```
GHCi> fmap ($ 3) ((4 :: Integer)+)

<interactive>:42:13: error:
    * Couldn't match type `Integer' with `Integer -> b'
      Expected type: Integer -> Integer -> b
        Actual type: Integer -> Integer
    * In the second argument of `fmap', namely `((4 :: Integer) +)'
      In the expression: fmap ($ 3) ((4 :: Integer) +)
      In an equation for `it': it = fmap ($ 3) ((4 :: Integer) +)
    * Relevant bindings include
        it :: Integer -> b (bound at <interactive>:42:1)
```

Comment: Thank you @duplode, I can't parse understanding from this error for now. The problematic step is `fmap ($ 3) (4+) :: (Num (a -> b), Num a) => (a -> b) -> b`. I would expect that it return `a` and not `(a->b)->b`. Do you have any suggestion what I could study to understand better this type of evaluation ?

Comment: @ŠefčíkováJana As leftaroundabout explains in his answer, the type would be `Num a => a`, as you expected, if `fmap` wasn't there. In this case, `fmap` leads `($ 3)` to be applied to the *result* of `(4+)`, and not to `(4+)` itself. On "Do you have any suggestion what I could study to understand better this type of evaluation ?", there are a few questions here that illustrate the procedure rather well. I'll come back with a link shortly.

Comment: @ŠefčíkováJana [Here is a decent, if a little contrived, example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43428053/2751851) of doing it in a systematic way. It is basically a matter of starting "from the outside" (in your case, from the type of `fmap`) and working your way "inside" by substituting the types.